# Adding multiple files to py2app

Tags: py2app

How do I use py2app for a project with the below structure. All the online resources and documents show what to do for a single file.

.MyApp

├── Resources

│   ├── database.pkl

│   ├── images_dir

├── MyApp

│   ├── __init_.py

│   ├── file1.py

│   ├── file2.py

│   ├── main.py

├── venv